# iPhone6 running iOS 11 is eating my battery

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

My iPhone 6 recently got updated with iOS11. I observed that its taking too much battery power. I need to charge 3 to 4 times a day for my requirements.

What is the main reason behind is there any settings or other things can i do, so that i can save my battery power.

Comment: What have you done already to address your problem?  Have you reviewed the [battery info](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/) provided by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 11 has severe battery performance issues. Please see the discussion on [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8118787?start=0&tstart=0). Most of the responses show that the problem is common and will not be solved in the short term. (Some users state that even iOS 11.1 beta didn't solve the problem)

For now, the only solution to the problem seems to be downgrading back to 10.3.3.

I hope Apple gets out of this mess as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the battery drain issue on my iPhone 6 in iOS 11. Reboot my iPhone, seems not work, maybe you can have a try. 
Or you can reset settings, turn off background app refresh.
By the way, you can upgrade to the latest version, new iOS version always contains bugs fix. Now the newest is iOS 11.0.3.